# How to use indices during Map?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to map a function on each element at the "deepest" level of a list.

The list can have an arbitrary number of dimensions.

The function needs the indices of the element to which it is being mapped.

How can I determine the indices of an element during mapping ?

Comment: for example?${}$

Comment: does `Map[MapIndexed[foo, #] &, list, {-2}]` or 
`MapIndexed[foo, list, {Depth[list] - 1}]` give what you need?

Comment: Yes, MapIndexed provides exactly what I need.  Thanks AFT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html):

```
list = {a, {{b, c}, {d, e}}};

MapIndexed[foo, list, {Depth[list] - 1}]
```

> {a, {{foo[b, {2, 1, 1}], foo[c, {2, 1, 2}]}, {foo[d, {2, 2, 1}], foo[e, {2, 2, 2}]}}}